# R read.csv truncating the digits of 19digit customer ID

Tags: r

I have a 19 digit customer ID and while importing using read.csv , R is altering the last few digits and i am not able to read in the correct customer ID.

```
data= read.csv("filename.csv")
options("scipen"=100, "digits"=19)
```

Comment: is it a problem with field separation? Give us a small preview of the data. R does not just chop up numbers.

Comment: @ECII you forgot about integer limits.

Answer (score 2):

R stores numbers in 32 bit integers or 64 bit double precision.  You can't store 19 digits in either of those formats, so you want to read your customer ID as a string.  But R will detect it as a number if it is all digits.

So the solution is to tell read.csv() that it is a string, e.g.

```
data <- read.csv("filename.csv", colClasses="character")
```

which says all columns are character; it's also possible to give types for each individual column.  See the help page.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the data to be read in as `floating point numbers`.  One option other than reading as a `string` is using the `bit64`

```
library(bit64)
data <- read.csv('filename.csv', colClasses='integer64')
```

Comment: this assumes that all columns can be cast an a (long) integer. If it is mixed data, this may not be true. G. Grothendieck's solution avoids this.

Comment: @PaulBailey  Yes, you are right.  I assumed in that way and I think G.Grothendieck's solution is more general.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `numerals` argument:

```
read.csv("filename.csv", numerals = "no.loss")
```

See [?type.convert](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/type.convert.html) for information on the `numerals` argument.